What actually is diffraction?
According to Huygens the slit has aether in it and hence generates secondary wavelets. But after the Michelson Morley experiment which failed to find the existence of aether and keeping in view the success of relativistic kinematics, we believe there is no aether. So how to explain diffraction without using the concept of secondary wavelets? and also tell what restriction should be imposed on slit size  and why?
Provide the best intuition.

These are two quite different questions and should be split into two posts.

"But after the michelson morely experiment,we know there is no ether." - that wasn't what the experiment showed, and aether remains current (if also somewhat neglected) science. The MM experiment was not designed to falsify the concept of the aether - it was designed to detect the Earth's movement in the aether, and when (unexpectedly) it did not detect any movement, relativity was devised over the subsequent decades to describe why such movement in the aether would be undetectable.

@Steve could you provide sources about aether being current science? Despite MM being designed for different purposes, relativity was developed without any reference about aether

@Ruffolo, maybe refer to some of Einstein and Lorentz's own correspondence on the very topic? This Q&A covers a fair bit, it's easy to find info: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13081/did-lorentz-remain-an-ether-advocate-till-his-death. As for relativity being developed "without any reference to aether", you do realise that Lorentz's name appears in fundamental relativity concepts (like the "Lorentz transform" and "Lorentz factor"), and that he and others developed them explicitly to model (what they regarded as...) the aether?

You might be interested in Kirchhoff's scalar diffraction theory, as well as a more accurate vector diffraction theory (both discussed to some extent in Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics, Chapters 9-10). There the Huygens-Fresnel principle arises as a consequence of the wave equation and boundary conditions. On an intuitive level, I think of the secondary wavelets as being generated by induced charges and currents on the surface of the slits.


Why should the slit size be comparable to that of wavelength of light?

Diffraction happens for a slit of any width, but it's not the slit per se that causes diffraction. It's the edges of the slit that matter. Light* is diffracted when it passes within some distance on the order of a wavelength of any obstacle. If the slit is wide, then a lot of the light that gets through is not diffracted because it doesn't come close enough to an edge, and the huge amount of un-diffracted light that gets through makes the much smaller amount of diffracted light much less noticeable. When the slit is sufficiently narrow, on the other hand, then virtually all of the light that passes through will be close enough to an edge to be diffracted.

* The same thing is true for any kind of wave, not just light. You can find some interesting images if you search in Google for "water wave diffraction."

Well, I don't think the 'edges' have anything to do with it. The presence of slits filters the allowable transverse momentum of the transmitted wave. The transverse momentum state is now the Fourier transform of the slit structure.

@JonCuster, I don't understand it at such a deep, mathematical level, but does diffraction not happen at the edge of a "half-slit?" (That would be the edge of an obstacle, for which there is no corresponding opposite edge.) And if edges have nothing to do with it, then what is "slit structure" if you take away the edges?

You are still filtering allowable transverse momentum by the half-space. Take the Fourier transform of the Heaviside function.
